# CGI script not executing but displaying content after installing mooshak

Tags: cgi-bin

Recently, I downloaded and installed [mooshak](https://mooshak.dcc.fc.up.pt/) in Ubuntu 14.04. I followed all the steps given in the requirements and installation page.

When I try to access `http://localhost/~mooshak`, I'm being redirected to `http://localhost/~mooshak/cgi-bin/execute` and the following content is being displayed :

```
#!/bin/sh
# the next line restarts using tclsh \
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/contrib/bin  ; exec tclsh "$0" "$@"

#-*-Mode: TCL; iso-accents-mode: t;-*-  

cd ../..

lappend auto_path packages

source .config

execute::command_line
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? This is the content of my `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf` file :

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all granted
        </Limit>
        <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
            Require all denied
        </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/*/public_html/cgi-bin>
        Options +ExecCGI -Includes -Indexes
        SetHandler cgi-script
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the modules `userdir` and `suexec` are enabled in Apache2. If needed execute the following commands

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/userdir.conf
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/userdir.load
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/suexec.load
```

You will need to restart Apache to activate the configuration.

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```